# SQL server : split string function only return part of string

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I found this SQL split string function on internet, but when I pass a string contains 700+ items in it, separated by commas, it only generate a table variable with 280 rows, can some help me to identify where's the problem?

The code:

```
ALTER  FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Split](@text nvarchar(MAX), @delimiter varchar(20) = ' ')
RETURNS @Strings TABLE
(    
  position int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  value nvarchar(MAX)   
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @index int
SET @index = -1 

WHILE (LEN(@text) > 0) 

  BEGIN 
    SET @index = CHARINDEX(@delimiter , @text)  
    IF (@index = 0) AND (LEN(@text) > 0)  
      BEGIN  
        INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (@text)
          BREAK  
      END 

    IF (@index > 1)  
      BEGIN  
        INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (LEFT(@text, @index - 1))   
        SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index))  
      END 
    ELSE
      SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index)) 
    END
  RETURN

END
```

This is the code I used to test it:

```
 SELECT * FROM fn_Split(@string,',');
```

@String is nvarchar(MAX) contains 700+ items, but it only returns a table with 280 rows.

Comment: The code you use to test refers a function called `LRMWEB_fn_Split`, yet the code shown above defines a function called `fn_Split`. Are you sure you're calling the correct function? Furthermore, how long is your @string-parameter? Note that nvarchar(MAX) cannot hold more than 4000 characters.

Comment: @Dan,Sorry it's just a typo when I write the question, fixed.

Comment: Ok - what about the length of the content going into the @string-parameter? It will get truncated at 4000 characters, meaning you will only get ~280 items if their average length is 13 characters.

Comment: @Dan, maybe I'm wrong, but I thought nvarchar(MAX) can store up to 2GB of data.

Comment: It seems you are right, actually. Could you try calling the function with a string consisting of many 1-character items: `a,a,a,a,a,a,a ...`? Just to see if it still cuts off after 280 items.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/966-sql-charindex-has-data-size-limitations.htm) has something to do with the function not working correctly. Could you try to replace `CHARINDEX(@delimiter , @text)` in the code above, with `PATINDEX('%' + @delimiter + '%' , @text)`.

Comment: I also believe the problem has to do with CHARINDEX. In my experience CHARINDEX has a limitation of about 7000 characters.

Comment: Nvarchar (max) can only hold 4000 characters as a fixed string. So the original theory that your string is too long still holds water.  Test it by doing `print len (@string)` before calling the udf.

Comment: @Dan, I tried with 2000 'a's, it works correctly, suppose my items are too long which exceed the limit? the items in string are something like: "communicationtestingproblem.csproj"

Comment: UPDATE: I tried 6000 'a' in that function, it only have 4000 rows, @JiggsJedi is right, is there any way I can get a larger variable to store a huge string?

Comment: Varchar (max)  can do 8000 if you don't need unicode.  I have an xml based function that should help... give me a few to get online and ill post it if there is no other solution.

Comment: In the mean time how are you generating the string ?  Can u post that code?

Comment: @JiggsJedi, I need something way bigger than 8000 characters, right now I have something around 250000 characters and it's still growing. Looking forward for your xml based solution. Suppose I can also try array instead of a string, but I'm not sure how to handle array in sql....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the XML solution I spoke of...

I'm unclear how you are generating your `@string` variable, but that method will need to change.

Start your `@string` with `<M>` and end it with `</M>`.  Then rather than using a ',' to separate your values, use `</M><M>` instead.

I tested this in SSMS, by copy/pasting my string value and holding paste until my line number was at well over 20K.  The first `LEN()` actually returned a length of over 19K.  I'm showing the `datalength()` of the xml as well, which is just for demonstration.

I use this method to handle data in a csv-type column in a vendors application db, and turn it into a column of usable data.  I have also used the method you show above.  This method is much faster than any other method I've tried.

Edit:  If this doesn't help -- tell us more.  How are you generating this @string, maybe we can propose a better option than stuffing it in a csv string.

Hope this helps, here it is:

```
DECLARE @string XML
SET @string = '<M>hello</M><M>world</M><M>hello</M><M>world</M><M>hello</M><M>world</M>'

SELECT LEN(CAST(@string AS NVARCHAR(MAX)))
SELECT DATALENGTH(@string)

SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS StringVal
FROM  (SELECT @string AS String) AS A 
CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
--WHERE LEN(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'))>1
```

Here is how it could work if your original variable is a VARCHAR in case other people come across this answer in the future.

```
declare @string2 varchar(max)
set @string2 = 'hello,world,hello,world,hello,world'

SELECT Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(max)') AS String
FROM (SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(CAST(@string2 AS VARCHAR(MAX)), ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String) AS A 
CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
--WHERE LEN(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(max)'))>1
```

If you were holding the csv in a column you'd use something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.UserID,  
       Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(max)') AS String
FROM  (SELECT UserID,  
              CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(CAST(someCSVListColumn AS VARCHAR), ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
       FROM #someTable) AS A 
CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
--WHERE LEN(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(max)'))>1
```

Comment: sorry, didnt see this at beginning,  just tried it in database today, it works really well, thank you so much. One more thing: how to pass this xml parameter in c#? com.Parameters.Add("@projectlist", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = test, should I just change nvarchar to xml?

Comment: I'm not a c# guy, but I believe this might help you http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/12/aspnet-send-xml-file-as-parameter-to.html

Answer (score 0):

Try This Function...
I don't have time to check your function logic..

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[UDF_Split](@String varchar(8000), @Delimiter char(1))     
returns @temptable TABLE (ID int Identity(1,1),Value varchar(8000))     
as     
begin     
declare @idx int     
declare @slice varchar(8000)     

select @idx = 1     
    if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return     

while @idx!= 0     
begin     
    set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)     
    if @idx!=0     
        set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)     
    else     
        set @slice = @String     

    if(len(@slice)>0)
        insert into @temptable(Value) values(@slice)     

    set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)     
    if len(@String) = 0 break     
end 
return     
end
```