# SQL Split Data to Multiple Rows from Multiple Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a single column table Tickets with column named ID

```
ID 

0688E0734    0688F073     
0781B0713     
0958F02134   0958F03124   0958G033
...
```

I would like to split the individual IDs into separate rows in the following fashion:

```
ID

0688E0734 
0688F073     
0781B0713   
0958F02134   
0958F03124   
0958G033
```

When there are multiple IDs in the same row, they are seperated by either 3,4, or 5 spaces.

I have tried doing

```
select replace(replace(ID,'   ',','),' ','') from Tickets
```

This gave me

```
0748A014,0748A0212,
0747F0124,0747G0113,
0777A054,0777A0624,0777A072,0777B071
```

However now, I am confused how to split multiple rows into even more multiple rows
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please do not edit the tables. I put them correctly.

Comment: Duplicate.  There are a ton of posts on how to split strings by `,` just replace the , with spaces.  Look for one that uses XQuery instead of a loop, its faster.  Ex https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24579055/sql-server-split-string-function-only-return-part-of-string/24579951#24579951

Comment: if you have up to 4 ids by row, you can replace spaces with dots and use `PARSENAME()` function http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006(SQL.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I generally prefer to use `XML` to split CSV list to table valued format. You can check this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_XML
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN 
   (  
      SELECT Item = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
          + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
   );
GO
```

and the following [article](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) for more techniques showing how to do this. Then, you just need to use `CROSS APPLY` clause to apply the function.

```
SELECT f.item
FROM myTable
CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings_XML (',', myTable.column) f
```

Now, you have already replaced the `spaces` with `commas`. In case you can have from 1 to X spaces and you do not want to replace it like you have shown, you can replace the space with comma. Then your data will looks like this(for example):

```
0748A014,,,0748A0212,,,
0747F0124,,0747G0113,,,
0777A054,,,,,,0777A0624,,,0777A072,,,0777B071
```

Just add a `where` clase that is excluding empty strings and you are OK. It will be something like this:

```
SELECT f.item
FROM myTable
CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings_XML (',', REPLACE(myTable.column,' ', ',') f
WHERE LEN(f.item) <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

What you got is a table where are multiple IDs encoded as a string in a single column. Very very bad in a relational DB world. I would suggest you christen this table "Source" and make another table target with a column ID of appropriate type. This might be also string or by the looks of it I see your strings might be hexadecimal numbers. In that case you could use 64 bit type big int.

1. You have to transform data in Source to some manageable form. I would suggest multiple passes where you would in first pass replace "     " (5 blanks) with ",". In next pass you would replace "    " (4 blanks) with "m" and so on. If there are unknown number of spaces between ids you might have to find more general solution.
2. From then on you insert data from Source to target using technique gotqn showed you in his answer.

One more thing: If your original data is in some sort of text file form, you might use some text editing tool to reduce blanks and convert them to line feeds and then import this.